# C и C++ Синтаксис printf() и scanf()

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf

Объясните, пожалуйста, простым языком синтаксис функций `printf()` и `scanf()`. Что это за куча символов с `%`??
Смотрел в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf), но там слишком много воды, на мой взгляд; ничего непонятно.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форматы нужны для того, чтобы указывать вид, в котором информация будет выведена на экран. Отличительной чертой формата является наличие символа процент ‘%’ перед ним:

```
%d — целое число типа int со знаком в десятичной системе счисления;
%u — целое число типа unsigned int;
%x — целое число типа int со знаком в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления;
%o — целое число типа int со знаком в восьмеричной системе счисления;
%hd — целое число типа short со знаком в десятичной системе счисления;
%hu — целое число типа unsigned short;
%hx — целое число типа short со знаком в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления;
%ld — целое число типа long int со знаком в десятичной системе счисления;
%lu — целое число типа unsigned long int;
%lx — целое число типа long int со знаком в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления;
%f — вещественный формат (числа с плавающей точкой типа float);
%lf — вещественный формат двойной точности (числа с плавающей точкой типа double);
%e — вещественный формат в экспоненциальной форме (числа с плавающей точкой типа float в экспоненциальной форме);
%c — символьный формат;
%s — строковый формат.
```

Источник: https://prog-cpp.ru/c-input-output/

Comment: Спасибо за приведённую статью! Все очень понятно и просто для новичка.

Comment: в первую очередь формат указывает **тип** элемента, а дополнительные символы форму вывода.